# Palestinian travel document from Syria

Tags: visas, transit, paperwork, refugees

My daughter lives in Germany but she still has a Palestinian travel document from Syria. She is travelling to Beirut through transit 3 hours in Sabiha airport in Turkey. Does she need any procedure, like transit visa or...
Thank you so much

Comment: What is a "Palestinian travel document from Syria?" Is this a [Palestinian Authority Passport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_Authority_passport)? Or a [Refugee Travel Document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refugee_travel_document), perhaps issued by Syria? Something else? What is your daughter's home country?